# Uniform integrability of reciprocal of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-integrability

Let $\{X_n, n\geq 0 \}$ be a sequence of positive random variables that are uniformly integrable.

Assume that $\frac{1}{X_n}$ is integrable. Then, is it true that $\left\{\frac{1}{X_n}, n \geq 0\right\}$ is uniformly integrable?

Comment: Uniformly integrable deals with the tail of the distributions.  So, when you take reciprocals, the tail deals with the behavior of the original distribution near zero.  So, can you come up with a counter-example?  For example, taking any uniformly integrable random variables $\{X_n\}$, adn then slightly changing their behavior when they take values in the range $[0,1]$, maintains uniform integrability.

Comment: @Michael In what sense does it deal with tails?

Comment: @sonicboom : The "probability definition" at the link below shows uniformly integrable deals with the expectation $E[|X| 1_{|X|\geq k}]$, so it considers only when $|X|$ is larger than a threshold $k$, and the expectation depends on how fast the probability decays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: consider the sequence $X_n(\omega):=1/n$ for each $n\in\mathbf N^*$. The sequence $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is uniformly integrable but 
the sequence $\left(1/X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is not even bounded in $\mathbb L^1$.

Comment: What about the case when $\overline X_n$ is the sample mean $\overline X_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then $(\overline X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is uniformly integrable but is the reciprocal $(1/\overline X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ uniformly integrable?

Comment: I have asked about the general case of the sample moments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4063063/uniformly-integrability-of-inverse-of-sample-moments)