# Uniformly integrability of inverse of sample moments

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, random-variables, uniform-integrability

I am interested in the uniform integrability of the set $\{Y_n\}_{n\ge 3}$ where

$$
Y_n = \bigg(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^k\bigg)^{-1},
$$
where the $X_i$'s are i.i.d observations of a continuous random variable $X$, $k\ge 1$, and $E[X] < \infty$.

Is $\{Y_n\}_{n\ge 3}$ uniformly integrable for $k = 1$ which corresponds to the inverse of the sample mean? What about $k > 1$? In particular, the inverse of the second sample momemt, *i.e.*, $k=2$, is what I am most interested in.

If it is not uniformly integrable in general, is it uniformly integrable if we restrict the allowable $X$?

Comment: not sure if helps but I think one can forget about negative exponent because $F_{Y_n}(y)=P(Y_n\le y)=1-P(Y_n\ge y)=1-P(Y_n^{-1}\le y^{-1})=1-F_{Y_n^{-1}}(y^{-1})$ and wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution#Related_distributions) that if $X\sim U$ then $X^k\sim \beta$ but the sum of beta doesn't seems to distribute as something known

Comment: @DanielD. I don't know what you mean by forget about negative exponent, if there was no negative exponent there would be no issue since a sample moment is uniformly integrable as long as the corresponding population moment is integrable.

Comment: oh ok sorry nevermind then, hope someone can be more helpful

Comment: What is a "population random variable" and are you assuming $X_i\geq 0$ for all $i$?

Comment: I assumed in my answer below that $X_i$'s are i.i.d copies of a random variable $X$.

Comment: @Michael I have removed the term population as it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Cannot be true in general: consider $k=1$ (or any odd $k$), take $X_i$'s to be i.i.d normal with mean $0$ and variance $1$, we show below that $Y_n$ is not UI.

Note that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(|Y_n| 1\{|Y_n|\geq M\}\right) \geq M\mathbb{P}\left(|Y_n|\geq M\right) = M\mathbb{P}\left(|\bar{X}_n|\leq \frac{1}{M}\right) \to M,
$$
as $n\to \infty$ by laws of large numbers ( $\bar{X}_n\to 0$ in probability), now you take the limit as $M\to \infty$ to obtain

$$
\liminf_{M\to \infty }\liminf_{n\to \infty }\mathbb{E}\left(|Y_n| 1\{|Y_n|\geq M\}\right)= \infty
$$

2. Since you are most interested in $k=2$, let us take $k$ is even. Let us show below that an "allowable" $X$ is the following: $X$ is a random variable with $\mathbb{E}(X^{-2k})<\infty$, then $\{Y_n\}$ is UI.

(Note that the conditions in 2 are sufficient but might not be necessary )

Consider the function $\frac{1}{x}$, it is convex on $(0,\infty)$, now using Jensen's inequality you get (I am using $k$ is even to make sure $X_i^k$'s are non-negative, also the inequality below is trivial when any of the $X_i$ is zero)
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^k\right)^{-1} \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{-k} .
$$
Thus
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\left|\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^k\right)^{-1}\right| 1\{\left|\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{k}\right)^{-1}\right|\geq M\}\right)\\ \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left( X_i^{-k}1\{\left|\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{k}\right)^{-1}\right|\geq M\}\right) \\
= \mathbb{E}\left( X_1^{-k}1\{\left|\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{k}\right)^{-1}\right|\geq M\}\right) \leq \mathbb{E}^{1/2}\left( X_1^{-2k}\right)\mathbb{P}^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{k}\leq \frac{1}{M}\right).
$$
In the last step, we use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality. Now $X_i^{-k}$'s are i.i.d random variables with finite second moment. Let us now consider two cases:

Case I:  $\mathbb{E}(X_i^{k})<\infty$.  Then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{k} \to \mathbb{E}(X^k)$ as $n\to\infty$ in probability by laws of large numbers. Moreover $\mathbb{E}(X^k)>0$ as otherwise $X=0$ with probability $1$, which will violate $\mathbb{E}(X^{-k})<\infty$. Therefore $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{k} \to \mathbb{E}(X^k)>0$ and thus choosing $M$ large we can complete the proof.

Case II: $\mathbb{E}(X_i^{k})=\infty$. Here also you can show that for an arbitrary positive constant $c>0$, probability that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{k} >c$ goes to $1$ as $n \to \infty$. Therefore again choose an $M$ large enough to complete the proof.

Comment: What is the conclusion of 1. ? And also what is the conclusion of 2?

Comment: Please see the edits. Thanks.

Comment: About 1, $k$ is fixed and the set $(Y_n)_n$ is on $n$. So, you can't write $\lim_{k \to \infty} ...$.

Comment: I have first taken the limit as $n \to \infty$ then took the limit as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: About 1, The set is $(Y_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$, not $(Y_{n,k})_{(n,k)\in \Bbb N^2}$ and $k$ is given. About 2, I think you mean if $E(|Z_n|) < M$ for all $n$ then $(Z_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is U.I ? I don't think it's true.

Comment: I think the confusion was that I was using the same $k$ for different purposes in 1. I precisely assumed $\mathbb{E}(X^{-k})$ is finite where $k$ is an even number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121088/discussion-between-suman-chakraborty-and-nn2).

Comment: I complete my previous comment with a counter example, let's construct the set $(Z_n)_n$ as follows: $Z_n$  takes the values $0$ and $n$  with probability $1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$. We have $E(|Z_n|) = 1$ for all $n$ but we can't find an $K$ such that $E(|Z_n|\mathbb{I}_{\{ Z_n >K \}})<\epsilon$  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Probability_definition).
$$ $$ 
$(Z_n)_n$ here is your $(Y_n)_n$

Comment: @NN2 Yes, you are exactly right. I just showed the quantity is finite whereas I had to show it converges to zero. There is a corrected answer now. Thanks for pointing it out, let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: Very interesting thanks. For the $k=2$ case I also think it may hold for a positive random variable $X$ with $X \ge c_0 > 0$. Because then $X^2 \ge c_1 > 0$ which means $(X^2)^{-1}  \le c_1^{-1}$. Then, using Jensen's inequality,
\begin{align}
Y_n=(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2)^{-1} \le \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2)^{-1}\le\frac{1}{n} n c_1^{-1} = c_1^{-1}.
\end{align}
So $Y_n < c_1^{-1}$ for all $n$, i.e. it is uniformly bounded, therefore it is uniformly integrable. What do you think?

Comment: Does your allowable $X$ also have to satisfy a condition like $X \ge c_0 > 0$? Because for $k=2$, $E[X^{-2k}] = E[X^{-4}] = \int x^{-4} f_x(x) dx$. Unless $X \ge c_0 > 0$ it seems $f_x(x)$ will have to decay fast enough to make this integrable.

Comment: You just need $E(X^{-4})<\infty$, in the case of $k=2$. Therefore if you have $X\geq c_o>0$ then it will definitely be true but not necessary.

Comment: Is assumption of the convergence of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \to c$ in probability actually required here? The LLN for i.i.d random variables gives that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \to E[X_i^2]$ in probability so it seems $\mathbb{P}^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{k}\leq \frac{1}{M}\right)$ will go to zero by the LLN without making any assumption. Or have I overlooked something?

Comment: No, this assumption is not required, I added the condition for simplicity. Do you want me to modify the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121126/discussion-between-suman-chakraborty-and-sonicboom).

Comment: @SumanChakraborty Apologies for the delay with the bounty, I thought it was awarded when I accepted the answer.