# can $1/\overline{X}_n$ become integrable only for larger $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid with a finite mean not equal to $0$ and let $\overline{X}_n$ be the sample mean. Though $E(1/\overline{X}_1)=E(1/X_1)$ may be infinite, could it be that $E(1/\overline{X}_n)$ becomes finite for some $n$? Can conditions be given to ensure this? This boils down to concentration of a mean (assuming just 1 moment) away from $0$, about which I know very little.

This question is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4063063/uniformly-integrability-of-inverse-of-sample-moments), which asks if the reciprocals of sample moments are uniformly integrable. I want to focus on the first sample moment: Is $1/\overline{X}_n$ UI? A necessary condition would be that for large enough of $n$, $E(1/|\overline{X}_n|)$ be integrable. If $E(X_1)=0$, that would not be possible. If the density of $\overline{X}_n$ (assume it has a pdf) is nonzero at $0$, then the reciprocal wouldn't be integrable. If the density is bounded away from $0$, the problem looks too easy. But suppose the density of $\overline{X}_n$ is nonzero for small $n$ and becomes $0$? For example when the common distribution of $X_i$ is beta(1/2,1/2), the density is infinite at $0$ for $n=1$, but numerical simulations show the density of $\overline{X}_n$ at $0$ sure looks to be $0$ once $n$ is greater than 3 or 4.

Comment: As long as the density is non-zero for $X_1$, then the density for the sample average will not be non-zero for any $n$, although getting small.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Is that just a proprety of convolution?

Comment: That was not my thought.  Simply put, since the probability of one term being zero is non-zero, then there is a non-zero probability of any finite sum being zero.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Are you misunderstanding the question?  For example, if $X_i\sim U(0,1)$, then $E(1/X_1)$ does not exist but $E(1/\bar{X}_n)$ does for all $n>2$.  The density at $0$ is sometimes defined by convention to be $1$ for $U(0,1)$ but is $0$ for $\bar{X}_n$, $n\geq 2$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I see the confusion, I buried it in my question my assumption that X is has a lebesgue density--no atom at $0$.

Comment: I understood that.   However if there is any reason why $E(1/X_1)$ does not exist, then the same reason applies to the reciprocal of any finite sum.  Using the characteristic function would work or try to estimate $\int \frac{n}{\sum x_k}\prod_kf(x_k)dx_1..dx_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked it fully, but here is some ideas:

- If $X$ has nonzero probability mass at $0$ then you have no chance.
- If $X>0$ and you can bound the rate of the cumulative density growth at $0$ with something like $\mathbb{P}(X<x)\lesssim x^\epsilon$ then $\mathbb{P}(S_n<x)\lesssim x^{n\epsilon}$ and you should be fine.
- If $X$ takes both positive and negative near $0$ with nonzero density at $0$ then I don't think it works (e.g. take a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ so $1/\bar{X_n}$ doesn't exist in the normal sense).  You will need to skew it $\liminf_{x\downarrow 0}\log_x\mathbb{P}(0<X^{\pm}<x)=\epsilon^\pm$ takes different values and also hope what happens outside a tiny nbhd of $0$ won't destroy a carefully crafted bound.